# JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted

Tags: java, android, jsonparser

```
private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.show();
    }
    String url = "http://learnd.cf/getOtp.php";
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",USERNAME));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone",PHONE));
        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create datas url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"GET", list);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.e("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag


        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

---

```
2019-01-12 13:09:36.585 11371-11569/com.example.rajeeshkv.learn_d E/JSON Parser:
    Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 
    [  
        {  
            "temp_id":"12",
            "temp_clg_id":"1",
            "temp_course_id":"1",
            "temp_stud_name":"a",
            "temp_username":"a",
            "temp_password":"a",
            "temp_email":"a",
            "temp_phone":"4",
            "temp_gender":"Male",
            "temp_otp":"2060"
        }
    ]
    of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This is a background task to pass username and phone to the database and get corresponding row from the database, and pass it back to the android using json parser. But I get the following error. I have tried a lot to fix this issue. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

i think that in a get request your username and phone should be in a hashmap not list of BasicNameValuePair

Comment: I used to print the one value from that json object and a colon appears in front of it. Can you pls help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

As the curly braces(`[]`) suggest, the json you provided is a json a array, not a json object.

Try this instead

```
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) ((JSONArray)jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"GET", list)).getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: I used to print the one value from that json object and a colon appears in front of it. Can you pls help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

2019-01-12 13:09:36.585 11371-11569/com.example.rajeeshkv.learn_d E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"temp_id":"12","temp_clg_id":"1","temp_course_id":"1","temp_stud_name":"a","temp_username":"a","temp_password":"a","temp_email":"a","temp_phone":"4","temp_gender":"Male","temp_otp":"2060"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

This means the return value is a JSONArray. But you are trying to convert it to JSONObject which is not possible.

Try

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"GET", list);
JSONObject json = jsonArray.get(0);
```

I used `jsonArray.get(0)` assuming there will be only one object in the jsonArray. If there are more items you have to iterate using for loop to get all the values in response.

Comment: I used to print the one value from that json object and a colon appears in front of it. Can you pls help me with that?

Comment: Yes I can help you. How did you tried to print the json object? which value did you got?

Comment: JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                otp = jsonObject.getString("temp_otp");

Comment: In the above code provided, I cant do anything so I changed my code a little bit. Now Iam getting the Json Array in the jArray

Comment: what was the result in otp?

Comment: Here the vale of otp is `: (four digit number)`

Comment: Just like `: 3453`

Comment: I think your code is correct. I can't figure out what's wrong in it. with `String otp = jsonObject.getString("temp_otp");` you should have got `"3453"` as result in otp.

Comment: I have declared the otp as global. So there is no need to declare it again bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> Volley

library and send request as `StringRequest`.